# How to list messages in Tropo

Tags: php, sms, tropo

I am using Tropo for sending and receiving messages in my web application. Is there any way to list all the messages in Tropo. Please help me out on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve past messages from Tropo. You will need to persist this historical information yourself for later retrieval. [Here is an example in a Tropo Blog](http://blog.tropo.com/2010/12/08/cloud-awesomeness-with-tropo-and-couchdb/) on how to store this information using CouchDB.